# Query in MYSQL;

Tags: mysql

The tables are:

```
Author (Author_id, Name, City, Country)
Catalog (Book_id, Title, Author1_id, Author2_id, Publisher_id, Category_id, Year, Price)
Publisher (Publisher_id, Name, City, Country)
```

a) Retrieve the title, author, and publisher names of all books published in 1999 and 2006.

Some book have two authors but when I write the selected query only one of the author name is shown.

```
select title, author.name,author.name,publisher.name,catalog.year 
from author 
inner join catalog on author.author_id=catalog.author1_id or author.author_id=catalog.author2_id 
inner join publisher on catalog.publisher_id=publisher.publisher_id 
where catalog.year=1999 or catalog.year=2006;
```

Comment: This title is clearly poor!

Comment: What if there are more than two authors?

Answer (score 0):

You should really look at proper normalization, but anyway...

```
SELECT c.title
     , a1.name author1
     , a2.name author2
     , p.name
     , c.year 
  FROM catalog c
  JOIN author a1
    ON a1.author_id = c.author1_id
  LEFT
  JOIN author a2
    ON a2.author_id = c.author2_id
  JOIN publisher p
    ON p.publisher_id = c.publisher_id 
 WHERE c.year IN(1999,2006);
```